# Progmatically submit reactive form in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

Basically, I do not have a submit button in the form. Also, the form component is a child component and I am triggering a function form parent to child.

So, in my child component I have access to the reactive form, but I do not see any functionality to submit that pragmatically.

```
myForm: FormGroup;

onValidate() {
  console.log(this.FormGroup);
}
```

I want to simulate submit functionality in onValidate function.

Comment: have you tried `markAsTouched()`?

Comment: `Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(field => {
  const control = this.form.get(field);
  control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
});` works for you?

Comment: I was actually thinking about trying this way. I think i will choose this route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. But if you want to get the value of the form after `onValidate`, you can do `this.myForm.value`.

```
onValidate() {
  console.log(this.myForm.value);
}
```

You can then do whatever you want with this value. That way you won't have to `submit` the form programatically.

You can leverage this value to do whatever you want with it, maybe POST it to an API to store it on the backend.

Comment: You cannot do an `http.post` ?

Comment: I have the workaround, but I was wondering reactive form must have programmatic option to submit, so that my form will update on submit.

Comment: What sort of an updation do you want?

Comment: Update the state of form. There is an option on reactive form updateOn: 'submit'. I want to show all the error message on submit of form. Basically i was trying to use angular form state as much as possible rather then using my own property binding.

Comment: if you go this way by submitting each time all fields are valid, you will end up by submitting many times your form, as soon as it is valid , it will be submitted, you can add an http.post inside `onValidate` but not sure this is good to go with.

Comment: I have a validate button which will first validate fields and it if successfully validate then i will show submit option. Yes user can click on validate as many time they want. So i think it's ok if the form get submitted many times for validation.

Comment: But then if you're showing the submit option on the successful validation of the form, why do you want to submit the form programatically? If would be the user who would submit the form by clicking on the Submit Option. I'm just not able to understand your rationale behind this.

Comment: They can click on validate button as many time they want. Every time they click on validate the form need to be updated with error message. The thing is buttons are not inside the form. If it would been there then the problem will be solved. Basically the validate and submit buttons are in parent component. And I would have the form submitted on click on validate, the error message should update accordingly. I can achieve the same functionality have an error object and bing to it. But I was trying to see if I could programmatically trigger the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

FormGroup doesn't give any option to submit however you can try with native form as -

```
this. myForm.nativeElement.submit();
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but it is refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be `markAsTouched()`

```
Object.keys(this.yourForm.controls).forEach(field => {
  const control = this.form.get(field);
  control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
});
```

See more information [at angular docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markastouched)